# How to obtain location of object during it has animation?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I am new in Android.
In my project , textviews have Valueanimator. I want to obtain their locations while they move. How can I do this? Which method is used to get x and y points?

Comment: use `getX()` and `getY()`. even though they will not give you the center point of the object but `getX()` will give the left most point of the object and `getY()` will give you the top most point of the object.

Comment: @RajeshK then, how to calculate the center point?

Comment: @xetrasu Sorry for the late reply. Incase you have still not solved your issue you can get the center using `centreX=imageView.getX() + imageView.getWidth()  / 2;
 centreY=imageView.getY() + imageView.getHeight() / 2;`. Hope it helps you.